# StreamCorruptedException when reading Bitmap from SD card

Tags: android, sd-card

I have a web service that returns a jpg.  I read this jpg into a byte[], convert to a Bitmap, and save it to the SD card.  The next time the user comes to this Activity, it will search the SD card to see if the image exists before hitting the web service.

However, the code that checks the SD card returns a StreamCorruptedException if the file exists.

Here is my code that writes to the SD card:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    new File(root + "/images").mkdirs();
    try {
        File file = new File(root + "/images", Integer.toString(intImageId) + "m.jpg");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Bitmap theImageFromByteArray = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        theImageFromByteArray.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Here is my code that checks the SD card for the existing image:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
        || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images", Integer.toString(mImageId) + "m.jpg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        mImage = (Bitmap)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

The exception happens during new ObjectInputStream(fis)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot arbitrarily readObject() like this.  writeObject() needs to be used in order for readObject() to detect a valid serialized object.

Comment: What about BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts) or one of the decodeFile() APIs it? [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)